# DevExpress MVC Pivotgrid: How to summarize/aggregate differently on grouping levels

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, devexpress, pivot, aggregation

I have a DevExpress MVC PivotGrid.  It has a header that at the highest level is Quarter, then Months, then Weeks.  The data that is passed to the grid needs to sum the data for the week, but average the week data for month and average the data (either week or month) for the quarter.

Here is a screenshot of the grid:

[image]

I want to have the weeks 201632, 201633, 201634, 201635 to be 0.1, but July 2016 should be 0.1 also (as that is the average) and same for September. Then 2016 Q2, 2016 Q4 should also have 0.1 (as this is the average).

Here is the code for the grid fields

```
settings.Fields.Add(field =>
{
    field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
    field.AreaIndex = 0;
    field.TotalsVisibility = PivotTotalsVisibility.None;
    field.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
    field.Width = 150;
    field.Caption = "Quarter Year";
    field.FieldName = "YYYYQ";
    field.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
    field.Options.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
    field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
});

settings.Fields.Add(field =>
{
    field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
    field.AreaIndex = 1;
    field.TotalsVisibility = PivotTotalsVisibility.None;
    field.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
    field.Width = 150;
    field.Caption = "Month Year";
    field.FieldName = "YYYYMM";
    field.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
    field.Options.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
    field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
});

settings.Fields.Add(field =>
{
    field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
    field.AreaIndex = 2;
    field.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
    field.Width = 150;
    field.Caption = "Work Week";
    field.FieldName = "YYYYWW";
    field.Options.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
    field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
});

settings.Fields.Add(field =>
{
    field.Area = PivotArea.DataArea;
    field.FieldName = summaryField;
    field.Caption = summaryField;
    field.CellFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric;
    field.CellFormat.FormatString = format;
});
```

I tried using

```
field.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.PivotGrid.PivotSummaryType.Average;
```

in Quarter and Month but that had no effect.  I have tried a bunch of other things but nothing seems to change the calculations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed to use a Custom Summary type

Here is the code for the PivotGrid

```
@using DevExpressPivotGridTest;

@{
    string summaryField = ViewBag.SummaryField;
    WWMMQ wwmmq = new WWMMQ();
}

@Html.DevExpress().PivotGrid(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "PivotGridProject";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "PivotGrid", Action = "Project"};
    settings.OptionsPager.RowsPerPage = 100;
    settings.OptionsView.ShowFilterHeaders = false;

    settings.OptionsView.ColumnTotalsLocation = PivotTotalsLocation.Near;

    settings.CustomSummary = (sender, e) =>
    {
        int nbrWWs;
        string fieldName = "";

        if (e.ColumnField == null)
            fieldName = "";
        else
            fieldName = e.ColumnField.FieldName;


        switch (fieldName)
        {
            case "YYYYMM":
                nbrWWs = wwmmq.GetWorkWeeksInMonth(e.ColumnFieldValue.ToInt());
                e.CustomValue = e.SummaryValue.Summary.ToDecimal() / nbrWWs;
                break;

            case "YYYYQ":
                nbrWWs = wwmmq.GetWorkWeeksInQuarter(e.ColumnFieldValue.ToInt());
                e.CustomValue = e.SummaryValue.Summary.ToDecimal() / nbrWWs;
                break;

            case "YYYYWW":
            default:
                e.CustomValue = e.SummaryValue.Summary;
                break;
        }
    };

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.RowArea;
        field.AreaIndex = 0;
        field.FieldName = "ProjectName";
        field.Caption = "Project";
        field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.RowArea;
        field.AreaIndex = 2;
        field.FieldName = "SupplierName";
        field.Caption = "Supplier";
        field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
        field.AreaIndex = 0;
        field.TotalsVisibility = PivotTotalsVisibility.None;
        field.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
        field.Width = 150;
        field.Caption = "Quarter Year";
        field.FieldName = "YYYYQ";
        field.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        field.Options.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
        field.AreaIndex = 1;
        field.TotalsVisibility = PivotTotalsVisibility.None;
        field.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
        field.Width = 150;
        field.Caption = "Month Year";
        field.FieldName = "YYYYMM";
        field.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        field.Options.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
        field.AreaIndex = 2;
        field.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
        field.Width = 150;
        field.Caption = "Work Week";
        field.FieldName = "YYYYWW";
        field.Options.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        field.Options.AllowFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
    });

    settings.Fields.Add(field =>
    {
        field.SummaryType = PivotSummaryType.Custom;

        field.Area = PivotArea.DataArea;
        field.FieldName = summaryField;
        field.Caption = summaryField;
        field.CellFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric;
        field.CellFormat.FormatString = "n2";
    });
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

---

```
public class WWMMQ
{
    private List<MyDates> dates;   

    public WWMMQ()
    {
        dates = MyDates.Get();
    }

    public WWMMQ(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        dates = MyDates.Get(startDate, endDate);
    }

    public int GetWorkWeeksInMonth(int month)
    {
        // some months have 4, some months have 5
        return dates.Count(d => d.YYYYMM == month);
    }

    public int GetWorkWeeksInQuarter(int quarter)
    {
        // most quarters have 13, some quarters have 14
        return dates.Count(d => d.YYYYQ == quarter);
    }
```

The trick was to define a Custom Summary function.  DevExpress already calculates all the aggregates.  For the week summary, I just use the Sum value as normal, but for the month and quarter, I use the Sum but divide it by the number of weeks in either the month or quarter to get the average.